# How to replace CLRF with new line in public key

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace `CLRF` with `\n` in a public key to make it a single string.

**Input:**.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvam/SXoPt4YccVuh1Pj/
GmVc/43Y58Weell9U8yIOzqHxWoDFwjRTAtZceVg7SY17ex5AsFDT+4pf46GXa7A
5Jd4u0VlCAC06GKkz0Dvfh4ETIfZXAwXhbvWUm1IgoERG46DAwIgseHe2bRhC56E
9KkVzbuivAan5vvOuKnZ9DkSKCCGpUo/UQfImbkFzNHGb9NPivvHf19pXio7vM7E
DmP1GYEhVUtRgUoUfNKqEKUoO3uueYMLUwL9ePjnNdg3chpneBihFPd0317FAc8n
0TibwVUR2iJrH5fEUNCczfnydQ2p5hKxvhYjswAe+PHktmlhbnmeBo16oUAuowxp
6wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This is what I tried:

```
PUB_KEY=$(cat keyfile)
PUB_KEY=$(echo $PUB_KEY | sed 's/ [^PUBLIC KEY]/\\n/g')
```

**Output:**

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvam/SXoPt4YccVuh1Pj/\nmVc/43Y58Weell9U8yIOzqHxWoDFwjRTAtZceVg7SY17ex5AsFDT+4pf46GXa7A\nJd4u0VlCAC06GKkz0Dvfh4ETIfZXAwXhbvWUm1IgoERG46DAwIgseHe2bRhC56E\nKkVzbuivAan5vvOuKnZ9DkSKCCGpUo/UQfImbkFzNHGb9NPivvHf19pXio7vM7E\nmP1GYEhVUtRgUoUfNKqEKUoO3uueYMLUwL9ePjnNdg3chpneBihFPd0317FAc8n\nTibwVUR2iJrH5fEUNCczfnydQ2p5hKxvhYjswAe+PHktmlhbnmeBo16oUAuowxp\nwIDAQAB\n----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But there is some issue in the output like first character 'M' is removed and 1 space is not replaced etc

Comment: It is already a single string, what you want is a single *line*. Also, the title of your question is confusing and does not fit. Also, why do you want linebreak characters (`\n`) in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't work as expected. It matches a space character not followed by `P` or `U` or `B`…  The `[…]` is a character class and matches only one of 
several characters. And since the `M` is not in your character class, it is deleted like the other missing characters in your string.

With GNU `sed` you could change all newlines to literal `\n`'s and remove the last literal `\n` at the end of the line:

```
PUB_KEY=$(sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g;s/\\n$//' keyfile)
```

Note that the string now doesn't end with a newline, but I guess that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to translate the newlines to an unprintable character then replace them with "\n".

```
SOH=$(echo -en "\001")
PUB_KEY=$(cat keyfile|tr -d '\r'|tr '\n' "$SOH"|sed "s/$SOH/\\\\n/g"|sed 's/\\n$//')
```

SOH = SOH unprintable ascii character
 
Thereafter newlines are translated to the unprintable SOH character and then are changed back to an escaped newline "\n" character.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a DOS text file with `\r\n` line-endings, you can replace these with the literal string `\n` easily using `tr`:

```
$ tr '\r\n' '\\n' <keyfile
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBg...etc...\n6wIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n
```

(there is no newline at the end of the output)

The combination of arguments to `tr` replaces each carriage return (`\r`) by the character `\` (which must be escaped), and each newline (`\n`) by the character `n`.

---

As others have pointed out, your command

```
sed 's/ [^PUBLIC KEY]/\\n/g'
```

to do the substitution of newlines with `\n` does not work, partly because `[^PUBLIC KEY]` just means "any single character that is not in the set `BCEIKLPUY` (and the space character)".

To do this with `sed`, you can do something like

```
sed -n 's/\r$/\\/; 1{ h; d; }; H; ${ x; y/\n/n/; s/\\$/&n/; p; }' keyfile
```

This assumes that you're using a `sed` that `\r` is a carriage return (GNU `sed` does that, but `sed` on OpenBSD does not).

The `sed` script first replaces the carriage return at the end of the current line with a backslash and appends it to the hold space (the first line will replace the hold space without appending a newline character to it first).  When reaching the last line, swap in the hold space and replaces newlines with the character `n`, and the final slash with `\n`.

The result of this will have a newline at the end (as opposed to the result of the `tr` command).